# Disable Toast Notifications for Microsoft Teams

Tags: windows-10, notifications, microsoft-teams

When you receive a message through Microsoft teams you get a toast notification and the icon flashes. You can choose to have these notifications enabled or not. However, when the "banner" notification is disabled the toolbar icon does not flash at all.

Is there is a way to disable the toast notification but keep the flashing toolbar icon intact?

I have disabled all notifications in the **Notifications** settings within Windows 10, but the toast notifications are still showing.

#### Edit

This screenshot is to confirm that Microsoft Teams does not show up within the **Notifications & Actions** settings window:

[image: Screenshot of he Notification & Actions settings window]

#### Edit 2

The version of Teams I have installed is 1.1.00.10955 (64 bit). It was last updated on 04/05/2018.

#### Edit 3

There is now a suggestion on Microsoft's *User Voice* forum surrounding this feature. You can follow it here: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32624690-turn-off-message-preview-in-notification-toast

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft Teams does not show up within the **Notifications & Actions** settings page. I've included a screenshot in my post to confirm this. The application was installed via SCCM on my work laptop, but I'm unsure if it was through the Microsoft Store. My IT dept. haven't been able to find a solution for this either.

Comment: Going to **About** > **Version** shows me `You have Microsoft Teams Version 1.1.00.10955 (64 bit). It was last updated on 04/05/2018.`.

Comment: I was unsure as to whether the version above was a desktop version or the version designated for Windows 10 S on the Microsoft Store, as you referenced in your first comment. I've now added the version to the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Windows 10 S UWP version, can only be installed on devices that have S mode enabled, if installed on a regular Windows 10 installation you are notified you don't have access to that version of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there is a way to disable the toast notification but keep the
> flashing toolbar icon intact?

It appears what you want will not be possible.

Based on, [Notifications in MS Teams](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/Notifications-in-MS-Teams/td-p/103702), the following is true.

> Here are the results from some of the testing I did in understanding
> the MS Teams notifications model.  I’ve run this by someone on the MS
> Teams product team and they tell me I'm "absolutely correct".
>
> [image]

The user concluded the following:

> You cannot turn off notifications for:
>
> - Personal mentions
> - Followed channels
>
> You can turn off notifications for:
>
> - Team mentions
> - Channel mentions
> - Replies to conversations I have started
> - Replies to conversations I have replied to

So it appears that toast notifications for Microsoft Teams cannot be disabled, still keep the taskbar icon flashing.  *It's possible the toast notifications still appearing, in the Activity Center even after they are turned off for all applications, is actually a bug with Microsoft Teams though.*

Comment: Based on the conversation it appears they were talking about the same notifications you are.  It's possible, all you have to do, is continue to adjust the configuration of your Team though.