# Dismissing teams notifications from Notification area (of windows 10/11)

Tags: notifications, notification-area, microsoft-teams, microsoft, teams

Applicable to windows 10/11 and Microsoft Teams users:

**Current way my teams notifications work:**

- message comes up in notification area (windows 10)
- teams icon in taskbar flashes with number of notifications

**Is there a way I can:**

- dismiss the notification in notification area
- teams icon stops flashing
- (*mark as read functionality essentially*)

Answer (score 2):

Notifications in Teams are somewhat annoying. You can turn off some notification features in Teams, as detailed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/how-to-turn-off-notifications-on-teams/d466ee7b-fc1c-458f-a740-b2c1e53e23ad) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/how-to-stop-teams-from-blinking-in-taskbars-when/decc661a-7c4a-4f7e-a729-afdee2f14824). I tried going via settings a year ago, and it didn't stop the Teams icon in the taskbar from flashing orange at me whenever something happened on Teams. At the time, there was a feature request that had lived for several years to make Microsoft implement a way to stop this flashing. It's linked to [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/teams-blinking-icon-on-task-bar/f0d4257b-0db4-4283-948a-02031d39460f), but the link is dead now. Maybe they finally implemented it?

I had some luck using [SilenTeams](https://github.com/Hypfer/SilenTeams). But it would reset whenever Teams did an update (which was at least once a week). Still, I wrote a script that would run this once a day, and that seemed to work. Then I stopped keeping Teams open, and would only open it whenever I need to do some work in it. It's probably the most permanent way to avoid notifications, but not helpful if you need to have Teams open.

Hope some of this can be helpful!

Edit: See also [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1321523/disable-toast-notifications-for-microsoft-teams?rq=1).